# Specifying execution context of COM object on creation in .NET

Tags: c#, com

In C++, an out-of-process COM server can be created like so:

```
CreateInstance<IServ1Ptr>(
    "IServ1"
    IServ1Impl,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
);
```

How can I do same thing calling the `Activator.CreateInstance` method in .NET?

I did not find an overload of the method that allows me to specify the value from the CLSCTX enumeration.

Is there a way to do this in .NET?